# $injector:nomod Module 'mean.system' is not available! running karma on new mean.io app

Tags: karma-runner, mean-stack

Just bootstrapped an app w/ mean.io

```
mean init myApp
cd myApp
grunt test
```

and the karma tests are failing with " Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mean.system' is not available!"

OSX 10.9.4
mean 0.5.51
PhantomJS 1.9.7
Karma 0.12.16

The packaged karma.conf.js looks reasonable:
[fragment]

```
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: _.flatten(_.values(assets.core.js)).concat([
        'packages/system/public/init.js',
        'packages/*/public/*/*.js'
    ]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE] Karma tests are now passing. https://github.com/linnovate/mean/commit/0d8eed13002cfdde4cc3e0f6cae24d3f8ca44d79

There is currently an issue open for this on github. https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/647

The Karma tests failing is a known issue on 0.4.0 new release. It is due to the way the javascript is aggregated on the fly.

For now you can safely ignore the Karma issue and pull early in the week once we have had some time to work around the aggregation issue. It will not affect the functioning of mean.io.

If you have any other issues you think might be a bug we would be really happy if you could open an issue or comment on the current issue